# How can I recreate the following queries using Polars syntax?

Tags: pandas, python-polars

I am currently trying to learn the Polars syntax by working through SQL/Pandas queries that I have done in the past.

Here is the SQL Query:

```
WITH fav_item_cte AS
(
    SELECT 
    s.customer_id, 
    m.product_name, 
    COUNT(m.product_id) AS order_count,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY s.customer_id ORDER BY COUNT(s.customer_id) DESC) AS rank
FROM dannys_diner.menu AS m
JOIN dannys_diner.sales AS s
    ON m.product_id = s.product_id
GROUP BY s.customer_id, m.product_name
)

SELECT 
  customer_id, 
  product_name, 
  order_count
FROM fav_item_cte 
WHERE rank = 1;
```

Here is the Pandas DataFrame after the initial inner join to allow for a MRE.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "customer_id": ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C',
       'C', 'C'],
        "order_id": [
            datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 1, 4),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 11), datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 7), datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 2), datetime.date(2021, 1, 10),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 11), datetime.date(2021, 1, 11),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 16), datetime.date(2021, 2, 1),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 7)
        ],
        "join_date": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        "product_name": ['sushi', 'sushi', 'sushi', 'curry', 'curry', 'curry', 'curry',
       'ramen', 'ramen', 'ramen', 'ramen', 'ramen', 'ramen', 'ramen',
       'ramen'],
        "price": [10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
    }
)
```

Here is the Pandas Code that I used:

```
df = (df
    .groupby(["customer_id", "product_name"])
    .agg(order_count=("product_id", "count"))
    .reset_index()
    .assign(
        rank=lambda df_: df_.groupby("customer_id")["order_count"].rank(
            method="dense", ascending=False
        )
    )
    .query("rank == 1")
    .sort_values(["customer_id", "product_name"])
)
```

And here is the output that I was seeking:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "customer_id": ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
        "product_name": ['ramen', 'curry', 'ramen', 'sushi', 'ramen'],
        "order_count": [3, 2, 2, 2, 3],
    "rank": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    }
)
```

Here is the Polars code that I have so far.

```
dfp = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "customer_id": ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C',
       'C', 'C'],
        "order_id": [
            datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 1, 4),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 11), datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 7), datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 2), datetime.date(2021, 1, 10),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 11), datetime.date(2021, 1, 11),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 16), datetime.date(2021, 2, 1),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
       datetime.date(2021, 1, 7)
        ],
        "join_date": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        "product_name": ['sushi', 'sushi', 'sushi', 'curry', 'curry', 'curry', 'curry',
       'ramen', 'ramen', 'ramen', 'ramen', 'ramen', 'ramen', 'ramen',
       'ramen'],
        "price": [10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
    }
)
```

```
dfp = (
    (dfp
        .groupby(["customer_id", "product_name"])
        .agg(order_count=pl.col(["product_name"]).count())
    )
    .sort(by=["customer_id", "order_count"], descending=[False, True])
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("order_count").rank(method="dense", descending=True).alias("rank")
    )
    .filter(pl.col("rank") == 1)
)
```

My Polars query doesn't account for/pick up on the repeated "customer B" orders that are tied for 3 items ordered twice each. Here is that output minus the .filter(pl.col("rank") == 1)

| customer_id | product_name | order_count | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| str | str | u32 | u32 |
| "A" | "ramen" | 3 | 1 |
| "A" | "curry" | 2 | 2 |
| "A" | "sushi" | 1 | 3 |
| "B" | "curry" | 2 | 2 |
| "B" | "sushi" | 2 | 2 |
| "B" | "ramen" | 2 | 2 |
| "C" | "ramen" | 3 | 1 |

---

**Edit:** Based on @jqurious comment below, the following might be the best translation but I am still curious if it is the best way to do this in polars?

---

```
dfp = (
    (
        sales_pl.join(menu_pl, on="product_id")
        .groupby(["customer_id", "product_name"])
        .agg(order_count=pl.col(["product_name"]).count())
    )
    .sort(by=["customer_id", "order_count"], descending=[False, True])
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("order_count")
        .rank(method="dense", descending=True)
        .over("customer_id")
        .alias("rank")
    )
    .filter(pl.col("rank") == 1)
)
```

Comment: Are you looking for the "minimum rank" per customer_id? e.g. `.filter(pl.col("rank") == pl.col("rank").min().over("customer_id"))`

Comment: @jqurious that is totally the correct output in terms of the analytical question. Which was, **"Which item was the most popular for each customer?"** 

I guess I would just trying to get it to look/be the same as the dense rank done by SQL/pandas.

Comment: @jqurious would this be the best of both worlds? 



`
dfp = (
    (
        sales_pl.join(menu_pl, on="product_id")
        .groupby(["customer_id", "product_name"])
        .agg(order_count=pl.col(["product_name"]).count())
    )
    .sort(by=["customer_id", "order_count"], descending=[False, True])
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("customer_id")
        .rank(method="dense", descending=True)
        .over("order_count")
        .alias("rank")
    )
    .filter(pl.col("rank") == 1)
)`

Comment: That gives `A, sushi, 1` instead of `A, ramen, 3` - I think you want: `pl.col("order_count").rank(...).over("customer_id")` instead?

Comment: You are correct! I made that change way too quickly and didn't take the time to read.

`pl.col("order_count").rank(...).over("customer_id")` seems to be the ticket!

Comment: I just found [`.mode()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.mode.html#polars.Expr.mode) which appears to be the technical term for what your query calculates. It doesn't return the counts though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Apparently the statistical term for most_common/most_frequent value(s) in a dataset is [the mode](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.mode.html#polars.Expr.mode)

```
(df.groupby("customer_id")
   .agg(pl.col("product_name").mode())
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────────┬─────────────────────────────┐
│ customer_id ┆ product_name                │
│ ---         ┆ ---                         │
│ str         ┆ list[str]                   │
╞═════════════╪═════════════════════════════╡
│ A           ┆ ["ramen"]                   │
│ B           ┆ ["curry", "ramen", "sushi"] │
│ C           ┆ ["ramen"]                   │
└─────────────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the count at the same time - which seems like it could be a useful option to have.

Perhaps there is a simpler way - but you could filter and use `.value_counts()`:

```
(df.groupby("customer_id")
   .agg(
      pl.col("product_name")
        .filter(pl.col("product_name").is_in(pl.col("product_name").mode()))
        .value_counts())
   .explode("product_name")
   .unnest("product_name"))
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬────────┐
│ customer_id ┆ product_name ┆ counts │
│ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---    │
│ str         ┆ str          ┆ u32    │
╞═════════════╪══════════════╪════════╡
│ A           ┆ ramen        ┆ 3      │
│ C           ┆ ramen        ┆ 3      │
│ B           ┆ ramen        ┆ 2      │
│ B           ┆ curry        ┆ 2      │
│ B           ┆ sushi        ┆ 2      │
└─────────────┴──────────────┴────────┘
```

---

It looks like your query finds the max `product_name` count per `customer_id` (including ties)

I thought [`.value_counts()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.value_counts.html#polars-expr-value-counts) may provide a more direct solution:

```
(df.groupby("customer_id")
   .agg(pl.col("product_name").value_counts(sort=True)))
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ customer_id ┆ product_name                        │
│ ---         ┆ ---                                 │
│ str         ┆ list[struct[2]]                     │
╞═════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ C           ┆ [{"ramen",3}]                       │
│ A           ┆ [{"ramen",3}, {"curry",2}, {"sus... │
│ B           ┆ [{"sushi",2}, {"curry",2}, {"ram... │
└─────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But I can't figure out a simpler way to unpack/filter than:

```
(df.groupby("customer_id")
   .agg(pl.col("product_name").value_counts(sort=True))
   .explode("product_name")
   .unnest("product_name")
   .filter(pl.col("counts") == pl.col("counts").first().over("customer_id"))
   .sort(pl.all()))
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬────────┐
│ customer_id ┆ product_name ┆ counts ┆
│ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---    ┆
│ str         ┆ str          ┆ u32    ┆
╞═════════════╪══════════════╪════════╡
│ A           ┆ ramen        ┆ 3      ┆
│ B           ┆ curry        ┆ 2      ┆
│ B           ┆ ramen        ┆ 2      ┆
│ B           ┆ sushi        ┆ 2      ┆ 
│ C           ┆ ramen        ┆ 3      ┆ 
└─────────────┴──────────────┴────────┘
```

It also looks like you could use `.value_counts()` in pandas:

```
counts = df.value_counts(["customer_id", "product_name"]).reset_index(1)
counts[counts[0] == counts.groupby(level=0)[0].transform("max")]
```

```
            product_name  0
customer_id                
A                  ramen  3
C                  ramen  3
B                  curry  2
B                  ramen  2
B                  sushi  2
```